# Software for preparing images for the web

Tags: software-rec, publishing, image-manipulation

Is there any software that is good for publishing bulk of images to a website? Like building different levels of thumbnails and uploading them to an ftp site automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with publishing?

Putting them in a Flickr/Picasa like webalbum or on your own website?

Because in case of Picasa they can change the "size" of your image collection in bulk if you like.

Finding a tool that will also upload them to ftp will be harder to find, since a lot of the larger software packages will upload to their own website. Though perhaps you can set up a destination folder that syncs with your ftp. Takes a little bit more time, but get's it done just as well.

Or specify more precisely what it is your wanting to do, so I know what to look for.

Comment: I need to upload them to my own ftp. But yeah, Picasa can resize images in bulk and can even put watermark on them, so sweet :)